# progressbar not appearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI progressbar that acts as a timer. However when I open the page, all it has is "Loading..." (added in html) and nothing else.

Links to files

> HTML file: http://pastebin.com/Re0ZKVNY
>
> Javascript file: http://pastebin.com/zynA5MnY

I can't seem to find anything wrong with the code. Tried copy & pasting code from the jQuery UI demos, but nothing seems to make it work (with my code.).

Comment: Have you tried putting all the code inside the *ready* function? It may be that your #loading element isn't ready when your script executes (because all the timer and fading functionality starts executing immediately). And you should also decide whether you'll be using jQuery UI progress bar or set your element's with with CSS (so not using jQ UI progress bar).

Comment: @RobertKoritnik I'm not that good with javascript, so could you please post the javascript for this.

Comment: I am intending to use the jQuery UI style, but just replace the progressbar image to a animated one.

Comment: If all you need is just visual style than just set appropriate CSS classes. no need for all the client side functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're doing a few things wrong:

- you're trying to use jQuery UI Progressbar widget yet you're setting your progress bar's width using CSS (which actually manipulates usual HTML `DIV` element
- some of your code executes immediately and some on ready event

[This is some simplified example](http://jsfiddle.net/2YXmu/) that **doesn't** use jQuery UI Progress bar but rather a custom solution the way that you actually use.

But basically let me also modify you code and move everything where it belongs:

```
// Progressbar Stuff
$(function() {
    /* don't need this
    $( "#loading" ).progressbar({
        value: 0
    });
    */

    //increment progressbar
    var loading = $('#loading');
    width = 0; //loading.width();

    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        width++;
        loading.width(width + '%');

        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            loadContent();
        }
    }, 75);


    // Fade Out, load content, fade in.
    function loadContent() {
      $("#loadcontent").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $("#content").load("./content/main.html",false, function() {
          $("#content").fadeIn("slow");
        });
      })
    }

});
```

### Alternative

Since it seems that all you're doing in your interval is animate progress bar it seems reasonable to just [let jQuery do the animation](http://jsfiddle.net/2YXmu/2) instead. And since you're incrementing your progress bar every 75ms and it takes 100 steps until you load content, you should run your animation for 7500ms then. It also makes progress bar run smoother.

```
$(function() {
    // animate progress bar
    $("#loading").width(0).animate(
        {
            width: "100%" // animate what
        },
        75 * 100, // for how long (100 steps per 75ms)
        "linear", // how to animate it
        function() { // what to do afterwards
            // replace with your own functionality
            alert("Load content");
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Still the same, does nothing.

Comment: @Adam543i: I suggest you take a look at my code on JSFiddle then because it does work. And especially to my alternative approach, because it's not necessary for you to do the animation when you can let jQuery do it for you.

Comment: @Adam543i: Of course it does nothing, because your javascript file has an error. Take a look at  line 10 and change comma to semicollon.

Comment: @Adam543i: You can now copy/paste the code from the alternative solution here in my answer. There's also a link to JSFiddle that does the thing.